# Sound output from Dell U2417HA monitor doesn't work on Linux

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, audio

I have a [Dell U2417HA](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=5PRDK) monitor that came with my Dell Desktop. The monitor has an audio output and from what I've read the audio is supposed to come through the HDMI cable and I should be able to plug my earphones directly in the monitor's output. The problem is that this doesn't happen, probably because I installed Linux Mint 18 on the desktop.

Unfortunately, the Dell website only lists windows drivers for this monitor, and I haven't been able to find this topic on the internet. Any ideas?

PS.:

I have already switched to HDMI output on the sound configurations menu, and tried every possible option in `pavucontrol`.

I have the default 4.4 kernel installed. I don't know if upgrading the kernel to 4.10 might solve the problem, but I'd like to avoid doing this unless there really isn't another solution.

**EDIT**

I just found out that I'm actually using a DP connection for the monitors, since I don't have an HDMI port in my CPU (I didn't install this computer). But according [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/229088) DP also carries audio. So can I still get sound through my monitor?

**EDIT2**

Output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    59.94    50.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    59.94    50.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

Output from `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3220 Analog [ALC3220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**EDIT3**

Contents from [`/proc/asound/card0/codec#0`](https://pastebin.com/bcKgDcNc) and from [`/proc/asound/card1/codec#0`](https://pastebin.com/JTz04BRS). The latter one is probably the one that matters (NVIDIA).

Comment: Things to look at: (1) `alsamixer` (for correct card, left/right arrows to scroll) to see if anything is muted (`MM` instead of `OO`), though that's unlikely for HDMI. Play sound somehow, verify in `pavucontrol` that the volume meter of the HDMI output shows something. (3) Look at monitor menu, possibly there's a volume control etc. (4) Connect TV etc. to HDMI output and test if it works for the TV.

Comment: @dirkt OK, that was a nice comment. I might have found the culprit with your suggestion 3. I didn't install this computer (it's in my office), so I assumed it was connected via an HMDI port. But looking around the monitor menu I see that the video is coming actually from an mDP cable. I can't even find an HMDI output in my CPU. So I think my question changes to: is it possible to do this via DP?

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `xrandr` and `aplay -l`. I've never seen a soundchip configuration that would forward sound to a DP interconnect, but who knows ...

Comment: @dirkt Editted in the question!

Comment: Ah, Nvidia. I don't have experience with that, you may need the proprietary drivers, and possibly you need to assign the HDMI devices to the correct DP with `nvidia-settings` or as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529911/hdmi-with-nvidia-propietary-drivers-on-14-04-1). But that's all just guessing. Maybe ask a new question? Does Nvidia have `/proc/asound/card1/codec*` entries, like Intel?

Comment: @dirkt The `codec*` files are there, yes. I'll definitely take a look at the `nvidia-settings` things

Comment: Put the contents of the codec files in a pastebin, and edit question with link. If `nvidia-settings` etc. doesn't work, possibly one can do something with the HDA tools.

Comment: @dirkt Editted! Checked out `nvidia-settings` and apparently it can't be done there.